# ¿CollapsingToolbarLayout Cómo cambiar tamaño de texto en Java (getString)?

Tags: java, android

Cómo puedo cambiar el tamaño del texto en Java? Quiero cambiar el tamaño del texto en el titulo de un `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

> ```
>   collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.text_shi));
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede lograr cambiando el estilo del texto cuando esta expandido mediante:

> [setExpandedTitleTextAppearance()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) Establece el color y el tamaño
>   del texto para el título expandido del recurso TextAppearance
>   especificado.

o colapsado mediante:

> [setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(int)) Establece el color y el tamaño
>   del texto para el título colapsado del recurso TextAppearance
>   especificado.

ya que si estas usando un `CollapsingToolbarLayout` se supone usarias las 2 propiedades.

Ejemplo:

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.text_shi));
collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.StyleAppBar);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.StyleAppBar);
```

Defines el estilo y el tamaño del texto:

```
<style name="StyleAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Sí, eso lo sé, mi pregunta es cómo cambio el tamaño del texto, gracias @Elenasys

Comment: Te refieres al tamaño en el texto del toolbar!!!

Comment: Sí, eso es, el tamaño @Elenasys

Comment: @UserNameYo he agregado respuesta, prueba y me comentas resultados.

Comment: Solucionado, respuesta perfecta, gracias! @Elenasys

Comment: Excelente, saludos @UserNameYo 
ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ